# How to stop resource leak at HttpClient?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some code to download a file utilizing `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`. Now my IDE tells me that I have a `Potential resource leak: 'client' may not be closed`. The concrete code is:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I did some research and found `EntityUtils.consume(entity);`, but this doesn't solve the resource leak for `client`.

So my question is, is this really a resource leak and if yes, how do I close it properly?

Comment: Is this question similar to yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724193/how-can-i-ensure-that-my-httpclient-4-1-does-not-leak-sockets

Comment: From what I can tell, it is not similar

Comment: I believe that closing the HttpClient once you are done with the call (probably in a finally block) should resolve the resource leak. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e401. Does the IDE also provide potential fixes to the issue?

Comment: Those are `Closeable`-types and mine are the "non-closeable-types". So I am using eclipse and it doesn't offer a direct fix, but it suggested moving all the calls into 1 line like `HttpEntity entity = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request).getEntity();` and now I don't get the leak-message anymore. Not sure if it is considered a proper fix (also not sure if I should post that as answer or just remove the question)

Comment: I think you can post that as an answer so someone facing this issue atleast gets a fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find any other way and Eclipse IDE didn't have any other quick-fix available, I tried the only proposed "fix" which was to merge all the 3 lines into 1 line like this:

```
HttpEntity entity = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request).getEntit‌​y();
```

I am not sure if this actually solves the resource-leak problem, but at least Eclipse seems to think to